# Kafka broker throwing ConfigException Invalid value configuration log.segment.bytes: Not a number of type INT

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a single node kafka broker and single node zookeeper with the `server.properties` like below

```
broker.id=0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
num.network.threads=20
log.roll.hours=24
log.retention.bytes=107374182400
listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.36.0.72:9092
log.segment.bytes=10737418240
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.36.0.72:9092
```

The `zookeeper.properties` looks like below

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
```

But whenever I am starting the broker I am getting exception like below

```
FATAL [2018-02-19 17:01:10,772] kafka.Kafka$:[Logging$class:fatal:113] - [main] -
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value 10737418240 for configuration log.segment.bytes: Not a number of type INT
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:670)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:418)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:55)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:759)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:743)
        at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:740)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:58)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Kafka Server 0.10.1 running on Ubuntu 14.

Can someone let me know what is going wrong?

Comment: Could you explain what the value `107374182400` is? Any reason to choose it? Do you try to change, in particular use lesser value?

Comment: I could see that `107374182400` is exactly 100 Gb. What your intention for that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `Int.MaxInt` is 2147483647 as discussed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1670) . `10737418240` is crossing the maximum allowable value.