# Maximum value for fetch.max.bytes

Tags: apache-kafka

I was adjusting value for parameter `fetch.max.bytes` and I got some exception that max value as been crossed.

```
fetch.max.bytes: Not a number of type INT
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871262/kafka-broker-throwing-configexception-invalid-value-configuration-log-segment-by) SO question and it seems that the limit of this param is 2 GB.

However, I saw official documentation [kafka official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) 
. In there , they haven't provided any limit on this param.

Can anyone help understand what is the limit for this param.

**EDIT**

This is **NOT** duplicate of the question for which my question has been tagged to. My question says if kafka documentation doesn't impose any limit for fetch.max.bytes; but when I tried to put value > 2 GB it is giving error.

Comment: What value did you try to assign to `fetch.max.bytes`?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous: I want to fetch max possible data per poll, the higher, the better.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use any value greater than `2147483647`. This is not a restriction on Kafka side though.

You can see from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/cafdc1e7df7725c92a374ba9528f7974fe592196/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerConfig.java#L376-L381) that the configuration parameter `FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG` is of type `Type.INT` which means that you cannot use any value exceeding `Int.MaxInt` (i.e. 2147483647).

Comment: I agree, but doesn't it mean that in one poll the max bytes which can be retrieved is set to this value only?

Comment: @CuriousMind The documentation is quite clear: The maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. Records are fetched in batches by the consumer, and if the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this value, the record batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress. As such, this is not a absolute maximum. The maximum record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config). Note that the consumer performs multiple fetches in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter cannot be smaller than zero. The documentation contains this information:

> Column -> "VALID VALUES" shows `[0,...]`

Also, the parameter is of data type `int`, and thus cannot be bigger than 2GB. It's all well documented.